# Can you stream file-per-file, line-per-line from a .tar.bz2 archive in Perl?

Tags: perl, tar, compression, bzip2

We have a lot of compressed data that actually is a compressed taped archive of directories and its subdirectories containing XML files; e.g.

```
omega/    
- alpha/
  - a/
    - file1.xml
    - file2.xml
    - file3.xml
  - b/
    - file1.xml
    - file2.xml
    - file3.xml
  - c/
    - ...
- beta/
  - a/
    - file1.xml
    - file2.xml
    - file3.xml
  - b/
    - ...
  - c/
    - ...
- gamma/
  - a/
    - ...
  - b/
    - ...
  - c/
    - ...
```

The result would be files such as `omega.tar.bz2` and these files can reach size of hundreds of gigabytes.

Even though we are aware that this is an *archive* file type, it would be nice to still be able to use its contents when we need to. Therefore I was wondering if it is possible to read from these files in Perl in a streaming manner, i.e. without first having to unpack and decompress everything on disk or without having to load the *whole* `*.tar.bz2` file into memory.

I know that with [`IO::Uncompress`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Bunzip2.html) you can Bunzip2, but as far as I can see and tested, this would read the whole file into memory which is not possible with our large files. Example code below on Bunzipping (not including TAR).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2 qw(bunzip2 $Bunzip2Error) ;

my $filename = '/path/to/file/file1.xml.bz2';
open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $buffer ;
bunzip2 $filename => \$buffer
  or die "bunzip2 failed: $Bunzip2Error\n";

print STDOUT "$buffer\n";
```

Taking the TAR into account, there is also the [`Archive::Extract`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) module which allows to read a `.tar.bz2` file (type `tbz`) into an `Extract Object`, but again this would read the whole file into memory which is not possible with our ginormous files.

Because of my own research into the topic I think it is unlikely that it is possible to read a TAR of BZIP2s in a streaming fashion, i.e. line per line. I have no experience with compression, though, so maybe there is a way to reconstruct file lines given a number of data blocks.

Tl;dr: can you stream the file contents (line-per-line or similar) from a BZIP2 compressed TAR archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Compress::Raw::Bzip2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::Raw::Bzip2) which allows you to decompress bzip2 input chunk by chunk, i.e. in a stream. But since .tar.bz2 is first a tar file which is then compressed with bzip2 you would  need to first decompress all data up to the files location in the tar file before you have access to the data you want, i.e. there is no way to seek to the file without decompression everything up to this file. If you are fine with this you might be able to use [Archive::Tar::Stream](https://github.com/brong/Archive-Tar-Stream), i.e. feed the input from your bzip2 decoder into the streaming Tar parser. I've never used it myself but it looks like it was developed exactly for this kind of use case.

If you have the option to change the format of the input files I would recommend to use a format which stores the compressed files in the archive (like ZIP does) instead of compressing the full archive (i.e. .tar.bz2). This way you could easily seek to a specific compressed file and decompress only this instead of everything up to this file.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But if you use a ZIP, wouldn't the whole ZIP need to be unpacked before any of the compressed files can be accessed? Would this be similar to first bzipping all files and *then* tarring them?

Comment: @BramVanroy: with ZIP the files are compressed inside the archive, i.e. one can seek to a specific file and then uncompress it instead of needing to uncompress everything in the archive up to this file.

Answer (score 1):

All the IO::Compress and IO::Uncompress modules support streaming, including IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2. The example code you showed (see below) is using a convenience method (bunzip2) for the common use case where you want to read all the compressed data from a file and uncompress it to a buffer in one go.

```
my $buffer ;
bunzip2 $filename => \$buffer
  or die "bunzip2 failed: $Bunzip2Error\n";
```

Here is the usage for the streaming Bunzip2 use-case

```
my $bz = IO::Uncompress::Bunzip2->new($filename);

# $bz is a regular Perl filehandle, so can read it a line at a time
while (<$bz>)
{
    ....
}

# or a bock at a time
read($bz, $buffer, 1024);

close $gz;
```

If you can find a tar module that accepts a perl filehandle and is itself streaming you can give it an IO::Uncompress::Bubzip2 object.

Another option is to just let the "*real*" tar binary handle this for you. More recent version of gnu tar will automatically detect compression, and you can get tar to write to stdout. So you could just open a filehandle to the tar command, like this

```
open my $data, "tar -Of $file.tar.bz2 |";

while (<$data>)
{
    ....
}
```